# Cannot change UILabel text in a handler function

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a UILabel

```
@IBOutlet weak var log: UILabel!
```

I'm using SocketIO to create a handler for a call.

```
self.socket.on("starwars") {[weak self] data, ack in
            log.text = "George Lucas"
            return
        }
```

But it isn't working.

I tried doing the same in viewDidLoad and it works there.

Comment: You can even don't use ```self.log``` in closure?

Comment: If you tap the screen after that line of code has been run, does it update?

Comment: @chedabob Yes, I can. Avaan's answer worked. Thank you.

Comment: What's happening is you're updating the UI from a thread other than the main one. Tapping the screen makes the thread run and process any changes. If you do anything async (which is what `socket.on` is doing), you need to get back to the main thread (which is what Avaan's answer does)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try as below,

```
self.socket.on("starwars") {[weak self] data, ack in
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
       log.text = "George Lucas"
       }

        return
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the reason is `UILabel` is weak. when out of closure/block,"log" will be release. so your label has no text.

Edit: Where are connecting the label (as `IBOutlet`) make it like `(nonatomic, strong)`.